# ElasticSearch sorting based with wildcard in key

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I have a data structure something like this from query. I want to apply a sort based on the date in the object values.

```
{
  users: {
    "1234": {
      name: "User 1",
      joining_date: "2022-12-28T11:37:00.000Z"
    },
    "3456": {
      name: "User 2",
      joining_date: "2022-12-18T11:37:00.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my query so far.

```
GET /_search
{
  "sort" : [ { 
    "users.*.joining_date": { 
      "order": "desc",
      "format": "date",
      "unmapped_type": "long"
  } }
  ],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "_schema:users"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is with using a wildcard in the key. I have tried multiple combinations from the documentation but nothing worked so far. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript and Node?

Comment: Can you please provide index mapping ? what is type of users field ?

Comment: Also, you can not use wildcard in sort field name.

Comment: @SagarPatel Users field is a hashmap